# Unable To Remove Whitespace On String Using Python

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm trying to get rid of the whitespace on this list however I am unable to. Anyone know where I am going wrong with my code?

```
 love_maybe_lines = ['Always    ', '     in the middle of our bloodiest battles  ', 'you lay down your arms', '           like flowering mines    ', '   to conquer me home.    ']
    
    love_maybe_lines_joined = '\n'.join(love_maybe_lines)
    love_maybe_lines_stripped = love_maybe_lines_joined.strip()
    print(love_maybe_lines_stripped)

Terminal: 

Always    
     in the middle of our bloodiest battles  
you lay down your arms
           like flowering mines    
   to conquer me home.
```

Comment: See the docs for `.strip()`. It will only remove the whitespace from the beginning and the end of the string. Try `'\n'.join(map(str.strip, love_maybe_lines))`.

Comment: ...so `strip` the elements of `love_maybe_lines` before you `join`.

Comment: "strip" only works at begin and end of a string, never in-between. You have to strip each list item before joining them.

Comment: I thought by '\n.join()'  the list, they're on separate lines so the whitespace is on the beginning and the end now?

Comment: @Blenderinho "strip" doesn't care about lines, it only cares about the string as a whole.

Comment: I've tried it with a for loop and it works. What does the for loop do to the string which makes it work? Because when I used the for loop I see the same whitespace BEFORE I strip it as I did when I used '.join()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
love_maybe_lines = ['Always    ', '     in the middle of our bloodiest battles  ', 'you lay down your arms', '           like flowering mines    ', '   to conquer me home.    ']

love_maybe_lines = [item.strip() for item in love_maybe_lines]
```

That may help.